# cakephp2 controllers getting too big

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a cakephp2 app and the controllers are getting really big.  Is there a best practice for breaking out bits of code into other functions that are not supposed to be actions?

*Sorry it has been a looong time since I did this with cakephp1.0 and back then I think I called them _functionname, which seems wrong these days.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you controller has been growing uncontrollably, then it has accumulated domain business logic and/or presentation logic.

The solution would be to move domain logic back into model layer. Either put that functionality in `AppModel` classes (which might be problematic, since it uses Active Record (anti)pattern), or create *higher order* structures, that do not extent `AppModel` and instead would act as services from proper [model layer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208) implementation.

And presentation logic should go back into the views (or since you are using the Rails parody of MVC - in the [view helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html)).

Comment: Why was this down-voted ? care to share the details about the mistakes in this post ?

Answer (score 1):

Use below link as reference it will serve you better.

http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/05/31/cakephp-fat-models-and-skinny-controllers/

Comment: There should be newer articles on the subject. And more extensive ones. This one uses PHP4 notation and the message of whole article is "do not use query-builder in controller"